# How to order multiple times while ordering by specified row between every other order clausule in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Table with products has (other than description) columns: `availableNow`, `available1day`, `available3day`, `available7day`, `price`.

Availability columns contain number of product in stock in that period and each period is including stock available in shorter-preceding period.

```
# Example row:
availableNow = 0
available1day = 4
available3day = 4
available7day = 10
price = 24.75
```

How do I `ORDER` these rows in way that first are items for shorter period + `ORDERed` by `price` and after that are items for later period and they again are `ORDERed` by `price`, etc?

This is what I came up, but I soon realised that result is not what I expect. This first orders things by availability and at end by price...

```
IF (availableNow > 0, 0, 1)
, IF (available1day > 0, 0, 1)
, IF (available3day > 0, 0, 1)
, IF (available7day > 0, 0, 1)
, price
```

Thing is, once item is `(availableNow > 0, 0, 1)`, I want conforming rows order by price and not touch these rows anymore, then rest of rows order by `IF (available1day > 0, 0, 1)` and again order conforming rows by price and not touch it anymore...

```
# this kind of shows what I want, but result is not what I want
IF (availableNow > 0, 0, 1), price
, IF (available1day > 0, 0, 1), price
, IF (available3day > 0, 0, 1), price
, IF (available7day > 0, 0, 1), price
```

(feel free to edit Title, because I have NO idea how to name what do I want)

Comment: can you put a sample of what you have tried as a query already?

Comment: Sample is there... Second big gray box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, if availableNow is greater than 0 you want to order by it, but with those less than or equal to zero sorted afterwards. Same for available1day, etc.

If so:-

```
ORDER BY IF(availableNow > 0, 0, 1), availableNow,
        IF(available1day > 0, 0, 1),available1day,
        IF(available3day > 0, 0, 1),available3day,
        IF(available7day > 0, 0, 1),available7day
```

EDIT. Further to you explanation, possibly like this:-

```
ORDER BY IF(availableNow > 0, price, 999999999), 
        IF(available1day > 0, price, 999999999), 
        IF(available3day > 0, price, 999999999), 
        IF(available7day > 0, price, 999999999)
```

Bit of a mess. Idea is that if available now it uses the price, if not 999999999 (so those not available now will come afterwards). Then the same for the other fields. 999999999 is just a number bigger than any of the prices (chose such a number with a bit of care!).

Comment: Nope, I will describe it by words...
Show rows which are availableNow and order them by price, after that show items which are available1day and order them by price, after that show items which are available3day and order by price, ...

Comment: Added a further suggestion for you.

Comment: Thanks, it looks neat! I was close, how come I did not see it?! :) I put there 99999 as it is largest DECIMAL avaible for column...